# can we use json file as an inventory hosts in ansible

Tags: ansible

Can we use a JSON file as an inventory hosts in Ansible?

I have below format and I want use `db` as host.

```
prepackages: {
  db: [{
                packageName: "vim"
     },
     {
                packageName: "vim"
     }]  
}
```

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Not directly. What's the use case?

Comment: I have defined vars in above json to install packages but i want to use json group (i.e. db) as a host instead of defined in inventory hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

You example is not valid JSON. I assume you have valid JSON like this:

```
{
  "prepackages": {
    "db": [{ "packageName": "vim" },
           { "packageName": "vim" }]
  }
}
```

Then you can create your inventory file for Ansible using `jq` in this way:

```
jq -r '.prepackages|keys|.[]' < hosts.json > hosts.ini
```